# force SSL connection without read()

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

I have sslServerSocket with

```
setNeedClientAuth(true)
```

Client establish ssl connection and send client hello. But my serversocket accepts client hello and make other ssl connection procedures only after i call

```
read()
```

from socket input stream. I use StAX to read from socket and create XML. And i want to establish connection before read to process connection errors separatelly. I try to call different methods of socket and socket input stream to force ssl connection establishment, but no luck. I think now about bufferReader - mark - read - reset, but maybe there is another options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `SSLSocket.startHandshake().` It's called automatically if necessary on the first I/O, but you can call it yourself as well.

However probably what you want is not just the handshake but the peer certificate, which you can get from the `SSLSession` via `SSLSession.getPeerCertificates()` and friends. If you call `SSLSocket.getSession()` immediately after `accept()`, it will call `startHandshake()` itself if necessary. Better still, add a `HandshakeListener` to the socket, check the peer identity when it is called, and close the socket there if you don't like the peer.